# how to load Css in a textbox and save asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, ckeditor, .net

i want user to view in a fckeditor and save css  in a CMS where to start i tried

```
// aspx code
     <CKEditor:CKEditorControl runat="server" ID="txtckCss"   StartupMode="Source"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl><br>
//code behind
    string path = Server.MapPath("../App_Themes/White/Default.css");
    txtckCss.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path));
```

but it gives error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: in witch line you get the throw ?

Comment: i dont know what happened but now its working